# How to make a query that returns data from the last 7 days excluding Sunday

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a simples query that returns a list of elements and create date of those.

How I do an BEETWEEN or another thing that return only the last 7 days without considering sunday?

Comment: WHERE cond = anything AND condition != anything

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler option if I understand the question correctly.

```
WHERE a.datecol BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
AND  DATEName(WEEKDAY, a.datecol) <> 'Sunday'
```

if the datecolumn has a time component then the query may need a little tweaking to remove the time component from the where clause

Answer (score 0):

The "last seven days without considering Sunday" would be the last eight days on any day of the week except Monday.  So, this should work:

```
where datecol >= cast(getdate() - 8 as date) or
      (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Monday' and
       datecol >= cast(getdate() - 9 as date))
```

Comment: That's not how I read his desired result.   I think he wants all the data for the last seven days, except for the data that is dated on a Sunday.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . That is (to me) a very interesting interpretation.  I hadn't considered that, but I am still sticking with 8 days where Sunday doesn't count.  The question is clearly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

> As you didn't post your query,so i can't see what you are Expecting.
>
> but here a sample,in which i store the last 7+2 days in a table, where 7
> days for the week days and 2 days for week end date.

```
declare @date int=7
declare @curDate date=getdate()

create table #temp(dat date,day1 varchar(max))

while @date>0
begin
insert into #temp values(@curDate,DATENAME(DW,@curDate))
set @curDate=DATEADD(Day,-1,@curDate)
if(DATENAME(DW,@curDate)<>'Saturday' and DATENAME(DW,@curDate)<>'Sunday')
  begin
 set @date=@date-1
  end
  
  End

  select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from dbo.x8 
  where DATENAME(weekday,date1)<>'Sunday'
 and [date1] between   DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(),-7)   and GETDATE()
```

Comment: great minds think alike.... I think you need to go back 8 days, deduct one for Sunday and you then have seven days of data.

Comment: The requestor should run one of the queries, see the results and put whatever number of days in the datediff part that is appropriate for them.